# Find covariance of estimator and derivative of the log-likelihood function

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, covariance, unbiased-estimator, scoring-rules

**Problem:**
Given and estimator $\hat k$. The estimation method is unknown (so, it can be max. likelihood, method of moments or another method), however, we know that $bias(\hat k) = 0$.
Let $L$ be the likelihood function and $\ell = ln L$.
**Find $\Bbb Cov( \frac{d \ell}{d k},\hat k)$**

**My attempt:**
$$\Bbb Cov( \frac{d \ell}{d k},\hat k) = E( \frac{d \ell}{d k} \cdot \hat k) - E( \frac{d \ell}{d k}) \cdot E( \hat k)$$

As unbiased $E( \hat k) = k$. Also,  $\frac{d \ell}{d k}$ is score function. We know that $E(s(k)) = 0$
Hence, we have

$$E( \frac{d \ell}{d k} \cdot \hat k) - E( \frac{d \ell}{d k}) \cdot E( \hat k) =E( \frac{d \ell}{d k} \cdot \hat k) $$

I decided to take $\hat k$ into the differential.

$$=E( \frac{d \ell  \cdot \hat k}{d k})$$

Since the expectation is linear, I can take the derivative out of it.

$$=  \frac{d E(\ell  \cdot \hat k)}{d k}$$

However, I am still stuck. Am I doing something wrong?
Can you give me some hint?

Comment: Why would there even *be* a likelihood function when the estimator method could also be GMM?

Comment: So, you propose that if $\hat k \neq \hat k_{ML}$ than $Cov = 0$. But what would be the result otherwise?

Comment: No, I meant the whole notion of a "likelihood function" only makes sense in the context of "maximum likelihood estimation". Method of moments, for instance, does not *have* a likelihood function.

Comment: Surely. But even if we have an MM estimator, why can't we calculate the covariance between MM estimator and the log-likelihood function that is used to calculate the ML estimator? For example, we create $\ell$ and estimate some MLE. Then we estimate $\hat k$ from the task using either this $\ell$ or a completely different method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try things in the univariate case. I'll suppose $f(x; \theta)$ is the density and we're estimating $\theta$ with $\hat\theta$ which is unbiased but otherwise unknown. I'm changing to $\theta$ from $k$ just to be more consistent with the usual notation. I'll use $\nu$ as the dominating measure for these densities and $\mathcal X$ as the support.

We have$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$
$$
\E_X\left[\frac{\partial \log f(X; \theta)}{\partial \theta} \hat\theta(X)\right] = \int_{\mathcal X} \frac{1}{f(x; \theta)}\frac{\partial f(x; \theta)}{\partial \theta} \hat\theta(x) f(x;\theta)\,\text d\nu(x) \\
= \int_{\mathcal X}\frac{\partial f(x; \theta)}{\partial \theta} \hat\theta(x) \,\text d\nu(x) \\
= \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\int_{\mathcal X} \hat\theta(x)f(x; \theta) \,\text d\nu(x)
$$
assuming we're able to exchange integration and differentiation here (and this is an assumption; just because both are linear operators doesn't mean they commute). Can you see what this integral is?